# Searching through a file and seperate data in a file with a separator value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello I want some help with a code to search through the text file and to separate the text from a separator value followed by a rogue(stopping) value.

Each line of text in the text file is: for example with sample data:

`DAC11010|This is a Desk and a chair|$100;`.

In the above example has the `|` sign as a seperator value and `;`sign as a rogue(stopping) value. The separator value separate the text `DAC11010` , `This is a Desk and a chair` , `$100` the rogue(stopping) value means that it it is the EOLN(end of line) and ready to check the next line.

The separated text goes to 3 `ListBoxes` and the data added one after the other. The `DAC11010` goes to the `lstItemCode` , `This is a desk and chair` goes to the `lstDescription` , `$100` goes to the `lstPrice`.

I would like if someone would volunteer to help me program the code in vb.net. I hope I made myself clear.

Thank you [shannon].

Comment: That format is commonly known as CSV - it doesn't have to be actual commas separating the items. [How to: read from comma-delimited text files in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/drives-directories-files/how-to-read-from-comma-delimited-text-files). To remove the trailing `;`: [Trimming and Removing Characters from Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/trimming).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already done so, please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

I will not write the code for you. That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow. We help with specific problems you are having with your code. You don't appear to have any code.

I will explain one way your goal might be accomplished.

Declare 3 `New List(Of String)` variables to hold the data for the three list boxes. We will be looping through the text files lines but we don't want to update the user interface until after the loop so we will collect the data in memory.

You will need to import System.IO to use methods of the File class. You can use `File.ReadAllLines` to get an array of strings; each member of the array will contain one line from the text file.

Next, you will want to loop through the lines splitting each line into 3 sections. Use the `For Each...Next` type of loop. You can use the `String.Split` method passing in your `"|"c` parameter. The c tells the compiler that this is a `Char` not a string because `.Split` is expecting a `Char` Now you can use the `.Add` method to add the sections to the appropriate list.

After the loop, you can assign the 3 list to the `.DataSource` property of the appropriate `ListBox`.

Now write the code and if you have any problems ask a new question showing the specific code where you are having the problem.